# Find excat string in full dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am searching for a string in the dataframe, and would like to get the list of column headers, where this excat string occures.

My dataframe is:

```
df
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
apple  app       appl
banana  app       banana
```

Now i want to search for: `apple`and I should get back:

```
ColumnA
```

If i search for `banana`I should get:

```
ColumnA
ColumnC
```

How can I get the column header, where the string is inside the dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for matches with *strings* as the title suggests, you can use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to check for equality with a given string, [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to check which columns contain at least one match and perform boolean indexing on the columns of the dataframe:

```
df.columns[df.eq('apple').any(0)]
# Index(['ColumnA'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
df.columns[df.eq('banana').any(0)]
# Index(['ColumnA', 'ColumnC'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: very nice with `eq` and `any`, is `eq` faster than `==`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way

```
df[df == 'apple'].dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns
```